# Playframework - internationalization and routes

Tags: internationalization, playframework, routes

I need two language versions of my web site which will be located in **domainname/lang1/somecontroller** and **domainname/lang2/somecontroller** urls. What architecture of routes file allow me to avoid of duplicating controllers declaration for every language?

Answer (score 3):

```
*   /{language}/MyController         Application.MyController
```

should allow you to access both languages, and you then have access to the language passed in, in the controller, if you wish.